# Can I use "either" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

I wrote:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a context variable prefixed with **either** $, # **or** @# symbols.

When there is 3 symbols above, can I yet use "either"? if no, how can I say it?

Comment: Just drop *either* from the sentence and you'll be fine.

Comment: When there are three symbols. /a context variable with a $, # or @# prefix/ best to not use the verb  here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used [either](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/either) correctly, but the sentence would be less ambiguous if you deleted it altogether:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a context variable prefixed with $, # or @# symbols.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/either) says, "You use either in front of the first of two or more alternatives, when you are stating the only possibilities or choices that there are."

Answer (score 1):

> either

is usually for a choice of two, but you have three, you could use

> prefixed with *any one of*